# Merge list of python dictionaries using multiple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I want to merge two lists of dictionaries, using multiple keys.

I have a single list of dicts with one set of results:

```
l1 = [{'id': 1, 'year': '2017', 'resultA': 2},
      {'id': 2, 'year': '2017', 'resultA': 3},
      {'id': 1, 'year': '2018', 'resultA': 3},
      {'id': 2, 'year': '2018', 'resultA': 5}]
```

And another list of dicts for another set of results:

```
l2 = [{'id': 1, 'year': '2017', 'resultB': 5},
      {'id': 2, 'year': '2017', 'resultB': 8},
      {'id': 1, 'year': '2018', 'resultB': 7},
      {'id': 2, 'year': '2018', 'resultB': 9}]
```

And I want to combine them using the 'id' and 'year' keys to get the following:

```
all = [{'id': 1, 'year': '2017', 'resultA': 2, 'resultB': 5},
       {'id': 2, 'year': '2017', 'resultA': 3, 'resultB': 8},
       {'id': 1, 'year': '2018', 'resultA': 3, 'resultB': 7},
       {'id': 2, 'year': '2018', 'resultA': 5, 'resultB': 9}]
```

I know that for combining two lists of dicts on a single key, I can use this:

```
l1 = {d['id']:d for d in l1} 

all = [dict(d, **l1.get(d['id'], {})) for d in l2]
```

But it ignores the year, providing the following incorrect result:

```
all = [{'id': 1, 'year': '2018', 'resultA': 3, 'resultB': 5},
       {'id': 2, 'year': '2018', 'resultA': 5, 'resultB': 8},
       {'id': 1, 'year': '2018', 'resultA': 3, 'resultB': 7},
       {'id': 2, 'year': '2018', 'resultA': 5, 'resultB': 9}]
```

Treating this as I would in R, by adding in the second variable I want to merge on, I get a KeyError:

```
l1 = {d['id','year']:d for d in l1} 

all = [dict(d, **l1.get(d['id','year'], {})) for d in l2]
```

How do I merge using multiple keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `d['id','year']`, use the tuple `(d['id'], d['year'])` as your key.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine both list and groupby the resulting list on `id` and `year`. Then merge the dict together that have same keys.

Grouping can be achieved by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), and merge can be done using [`collection.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from collections import ChainMap

>>> [dict(ChainMap(*list(g))) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l1+l2, key=lambda x: (x['id'],x['year'])),key=lambda x: (x['id'],x['year']))]
>>> [{'resultA': 2, 'id': 1, 'resultB': 5, 'year': '2017'}, {'resultA': 3, 'id': 1, 'resultB': 7, 'year': '2018'}, {'resultA': 3, 'id': 2, 'resultB': 8, 'year': '2017'}, {'resultA': 5, 'id': 2, 'resultB': 9, 'year': '2018'}]
```

Alternatively to avoid `lambda` you can also use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
 >>> from operator import itemgetter
 >>> [dict(ChainMap(*list(g))) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l1+l2, key=itemgetter('id', 'year')),key=itemgetter('id', 'year'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@AlexHall's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997827/9209546), you can use `collections.defaultdict` to help you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for i in l1 + l2:
    results = {k: v for k, v in i.items() if k not in ('id', 'year')}
    d[(i['id'], i['year'])].update(results)
```

**Result**

```
defaultdict(dict,
            {(1, '2017'): {'resultA': 2, 'resultB': 5},
             (1, '2018'): {'resultA': 3, 'resultB': 7},
             (2, '2017'): {'resultA': 3, 'resultB': 8},
             (2, '2018'): {'resultA': 5, 'resultB': 9}})
```