# python string repsesenting multiple arrays to numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have a string which represents an nD array in the following format:

```
"[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]] [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]"
```

Now I want to transform this string to a numpy array 4x5x3 (int) (the size could be dynamic based on the number of values within the single and double brackets), something like that:

```
        /[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
       / [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
      /  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
     /   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]    
    /[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]   
   / [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  
  /  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
 /   [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]                  
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How can this be done efficiently other than looping on every character.

Comment: why is the matrix printed in a slanted fashion, also you are missing some commands in your string representation

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I have it slanted in order to show the depth. The double brackets show the size of the 3rd dimension.

Comment: Why do you have such a string representation in the first place?  `eval` works fine on standard list displays, it does not work with the `numpy` array prints.

Comment: well initially my data are in a different form, however I am applying some merging based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169083 which transforms it to the above format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)uate the string, transforming it to a tuple of lists of lists. Then convert this to a NumPy array. One trouble is that your string is missing commas after each 2D sub-array (i.e. after `]]`). To fix this we just insert these missing commas:

```
import numpy as np

s = "[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]] [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]"
a = np.array(eval(s.replace(']]', ']],')))
print(a)
```

#### Note on eval

Using `eval` is often considered somewhat dangerous, as it can execute arbitrary code. A safer alternative is `literal_eval` from the `ast` module:

```
import ast
a = np.array(ast.literal_eval(s.replace(']]', ']],')))
```

Comment: good approach. though i'd recommend only suggesting the literal_eval version, and talking about eval only in passing if you must, but not as the main answer.

Comment: thanks, that works nice. To be honest I was looking on `ast.literal_eval` but I am still new in python so couldn't figure out how to use it.