# SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Original Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051890/combine-or-merge-dictionaries-based-on-more-than-one-key-or-multi-keys)
This code works on v3.6.4 but when i migrate to v3.4, i got an error message: How would you rewrite this?

```
for d in [*x, *y]:
          ^
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target

=======================================
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

x = [ {'pid':111, 'sid':6, 'eid':123, 'x_qty':30},
      {'pid':222, 'sid':56, 'eid':6212, 'x_qty':2} ]

y = [ {'pid':111, 'sid':6, 'eid':123, 'y_qty':123},
      {'pid':333, 'sid':56, 'eid':6212, 'y_qty':112} ]

data = defaultdict(dict)
f = itemgetter('pid', 'sid', 'eid')
for d in [*x, *y]:
    data[f(d)].update(d)

result = list(data.values())
=======================================
```

Comment: `for d in x + y:` or `itertools.chain`

Comment: This is basically the same issue as in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297859/double-asterisks-error-invalid-syntax).

Comment: If your actual `x` and `y` lists are really large, consider using `itertools.chain`.

Comment: Closed as duplicate, issue addressed in comments. Actually, I would've suggested you ping wim under his answer for clarification.