# left merging list of dictionaries in python with multiple keys, filling in with zeros

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I am trying to essentially replace the pd.merge() functionality in script without using pandas.

If I have 2 list of dictionaries (below):

```
l1 = [{'key1': '2017', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 11},
  {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 22},
  {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 33},
  {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 44},
  {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 55},
  {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 66},
  {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 77},
  {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 88}]


l2 = [{'key1': '2017', 'key2': '20-30', 'val2': 1000},
      {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '40-50', 'val3': 2000},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '50+', 'val3': 3000}]
```

And I want to "left merge" using multiple keys to render the following result:

```
output = [{'key1': '2017', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 11, 'val2':1000, 'val3'0:},
      {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 22, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 33, 'val2':0, 'val3':2000},
      {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 44, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 55, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 66, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 77, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 88, 'val2':0, 'val3':3000}]
```

The closest I've gotten is by using [this as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997558/merge-list-of-python-dictionaries-using-multiple-keys) and the code below, but I am unsure how get it quite right (zeroes included).

```
l1 = {(d['key1'], d['key2']):d for d in l1}
all = [dict(d, **l1.get((d['key1'], d['key2']), {})) for d in l2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with pandas dataframes, pandas usually knows the number of columns and data types in advance.

Assuming all elements in each list have the same structure (keys in `l1` may be different from `l2`, but all elements in `l1` have same keys, and all elements in `l2` have same keys, then discovering the default type as well as total number of keys in each of the output dictionaries becomes an `O(1)` operation. Right now, given that `l2` has different keys, you will have to scan the lists i.e. `O(n)` operation, to find out total number of columns/keys in `l2`.

Refer to the `left_merge` function in the code below. It's more verbose but explains what's going on.

```
l1 = [{'key1': '2017', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 11},
  {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 22},
  {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 33},
  {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 44},
  {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 55},
  {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 66},
  {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 77},
  {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 88}]


l2 = [{'key1': '2017', 'key2': '20-30', 'val2': 1000},
      {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '40-50', 'val3': 2000},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '50+', 'val3': 3000}]

op_output = [{'key1': '2017', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 11, 'val2':1000, 'val3': 0},
      {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 22, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 33, 'val2':0, 'val3':2000},
      {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 44, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 55, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 66, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 77, 'val2':0, 'val3':0},
      {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 88, 'val2':0, 'val3':3000}]


def left_merge(a, b, key):
    # a and b are list of dictionaries
    # key is a callable
    # TODO: bounds checking if a is empty or b is empty

    b_index = {key(i): i for i in b}
    output = []

    # pick one element from a and b so we know the final columns
    merged_item_columns = set()
    merged_item_columns.update(a[0].keys())
    merged_item_columns.update(b[0].keys())

    # UPDATE: Above assumption of picking one element from list a and b
    # does not hold true
    # In OP's question: l2 has some records with val2, some with val3.
    # So it isn't like a dataframe where all columns are known in advance.

    # Discovery requires scanning all elements (sigh)
    # This can be done when creating the index for b atleast.

    b_index = {} # replaces the original b_index computation at the beginning.
    # NOTE: if l1 also has similar characteristics, it will also require a similar scan.
    for i in b:
        b_index[key(i)] = i
        merged_item_columns.update(i.keys())

    # TODO: determine type for each column and choose correct defaults
    # using 0 as default for now.
    merged_item_template = {k:0 for k in merged_item_columns}
    for a_item in a:
        merged_item = merged_item_template.copy()
        merged_item.update(a_item)

        b_item = b_index.get(key(a_item))
        if b_item is not None:
            merged_item.update(b_item)

        output.append(merged_item)

    return output


output = left_merge(l1, l2, key=lambda x:(x['key1'], x['key2']))
print(output)
print(op_output == output)
```

Comment: assigning lambda expressions to identifiers is discouraged: [pep8](https://pep8.org/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: @Nin17 updated - uses `key=lambda` in the call to `left_merge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first assign zeros for `val2` and `val3` and apply the code you got:

```py
l2 = {(d['key1'], d['key2']): d for d in l2}

output = [{**d, **{'val2': 0, 'val3': 0}} for d in l1] # zeros for val2 and val3
output = [{**d, **l2.get((d['key1'], d['key2']), {})} for d in output] # update
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': '2017', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 11, 'val2': 1000, 'val3': 0},
 {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 22, 'val2': 0, 'val3': 0},
 {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 33, 'val2': 0, 'val3': 2000},
 {'key1': '2017', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 44, 'val2': 0, 'val3': 0},
 {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '20-30', 'val1': 55, 'val2': 0, 'val3': 0},
 {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '30-40', 'val1': 66, 'val2': 0, 'val3': 0},
 {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '40-50', 'val1': 77, 'val2': 0, 'val3': 0},
 {'key1': '2018', 'key2': '50+', 'val1': 88, 'val2': 0, 'val3': 3000}]
```

By the way, for python 3.9+, you can instead use `|` operator to simplify the code a little bit:

```py
l2 = {(d['key1'], d['key2']): d for d in l2}

output = [d | {'val2': 0, 'val3': 0} for d in l1]
output = [d | l2.get((d['key1'], d['key2']), {}) for d in output]
```